# prevent twitter bootstrap from repositioning horizontal elements vertically until certain window width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i like using bootstrap for the responsiveness of one part of a page, and for the top part of the page, the code i've written so far works well in the sense that it positions the navigation elements side by side with a large enough window and when the window is made smaller in width, it repositions the elements on top of each other (like if it were being used by a phone).

however, the problem is that the vertical reposition happens too early, or basically, when the window is being made smaller but not quite at the cellphone width size, the positions prematurely reposition vertically.

this is what i have so far:

```
 <html>
 <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Walls</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://flip.hr/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="container">
 <br>


    <div class="row">

    <div class="span2">

         <p>Donec </p>
         <p><a class="btn" href="#">Click meeee &raquo;</a></p>

    </div>

    <div class="span2">

         <p>Donec  </p>
         <p><a class="btn" href="#">Click meeee &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>


    <div class="span8">
    </div>


    </div><!-- .row -->
 </div><!-- .container -->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a way for me to make it so that they have a fixed position until the window gets to a certain size and then they restack vertically? that's my real goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way for me to make it so that they have a fixed position until the window gets to a certain size and then they restack vertically? that's my real goal

YES. Media queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/Media_queries) (http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) is exactly what you are looking for! It let's you set different rules based on the screen size, you can set specific width until one point and below that point you can apply your current CSS rules.